# $(X_n)$ i.i.d. random variables, $\tau(t) = \operatorname{min}\{n : X_n > t\}$ - how do I find the distribution of $\tau(t)$?

Tags: probability

Consider i.i.d. random variables $X_n$ and, for $t \leq 0$, define the random variable $\tau(t) = \operatorname{min}\{n : X_n > t\}$. How do I find the distribution of $\tau(t)$? Also, I'm asked to show that if $p_t = P(X_1>t) \to 0$ when $t \to \infty$, then $p_t\tau(t)$ converges in distribution to $e^{-x}$. I am somewhat confused, is $\tau(t)$ a random variable for each $t$, or is $\tau$ a random variable with domain $\mathbb{R}$? It seems like a very strange problem to me, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

$\tau$, in your case, is a function of $t$, whose input is a real number $t$ (I assume you meant to say $t \ge 0$ in defining it), and whose output is a random variable on the integers. Or, if you want to look at it a little differently, it's a random variable that is parametrised by $t$, which means that you can examine its behaviour by fixing the value of $t$ and finding its distribution for that value.

Looking at it carefully, the value of $\tau(t)$ is the smallest $n$ where $X_n > t$, i.e. it's looking at all of the $X_n$ in order and finding the first one that's larger than the parameter $t$. So in distribution terms, $\tau(t) = m$ when $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{m-1} \leq t$ and $X_m > t$, which you should be able to express fairly simply in terms of $p_t$ since the $X_i$ are i.i.d.

Comment: But what does the bit about convergence in distribution mean? Is it like $p_n\tau(n) \to e^{-x}$ when $n /to \infty$? And how would I prove it?